# laravel 5 - when is a new session created?

Tags: session, laravel-5

I have changed the session driver of my app from `file` to `database` and found, that lots of sessions are inside `app/storage/framework/sessions` (~900) and now, in the mysql database.

When is a session created in laravel 5 ?

I thought when a new session cookie is set. Just wondering, because I think that ~200 sessions in ~ 30 min is too much . I don't have so many visitors. It almost looks as if every request makes a new session into the sessions table. I only changed the session driver. Did not change some other session option.

edit: This all is, because I wanted to build a 'n user online function' based on sessions. But with so many sessions, this would show too many users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel will create a session record for anything that hits your site.  This includes automated requests like bots, uptime monitors, or other pings to your site.

It's possible to turn this off for [certain page requests](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-session-for-certan-request).